# NumberFormat Exception When Convert Some Other Languare to english in android

Tags: android

I am Used to Convert Ressiun Language Digits like 30,00 to English by following Couple of code ...but It Gives `NumberFormatException`.

```
NumberFormat gereralformat = NumberFormat.getInstance(new Locale("en","us"));
temp_value = gereralformat.parse(et_input.getText().toString()).doubleValue();
```

Comment: Well, you're saying you want to parse it as an English US style number. 30,00 is not a valid English US style number.

Comment: I know...this is not US style...but want to convert it into US style...

Comment: I don't know proper way....So. please help in this issue...thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, It can help you in parsing numbers having comma and dot.

```
DecimalFormatSymbols symbols = new DecimalFormatSymbols(Locale.US);
symbols.setDecimalSeparator('.');
DecimalFormat twoDecimalForm = new DecimalFormat("#.##", symbols);//Two point
String finalVal = twoDecimalForm.format(DoubleValue);
```

Comment: I Have Input in Russian Language...Like "30,0000"... I Went to Convert in Native English Language...

Comment: It should work.I have faced same issue for Spanish locale.Just pass the double value;

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely because of the `,` (comma) used as decimal separator. English numbers use `.` (dot).

Answer (score 0):

That is happening because you are trying to convert a String to a numeric value (int, float, double...)

probably `et_input.getText().toString()` is with an unexpected character, such as `,`

So before call `gereralformat.parse` make sure that you have format your english number correct.

you can fix this problem doing this:

`String newString = string.replace(",", ".");`